# How to convert a file to SHA256 in ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am stuck at converting a file to SHA256 string. Say, if I have the file uri on a device, how can I read that file and convert it to SHA256? I've already have CryptoJS in my project.`

```
var fileName = fileURI.split('/')[fileURI.length - 1];
          File.readAsBinaryString(cordova.file.dataDirectory, fileName ).then((file) => {
              this.binStr = file.toString();
              this.fileHash = CryptoJS.SHA256(fileHash.toString());
          }).catch((err) => {
              console.log(err);
              this.error = err.toString();
          })
```

`

Comment: `CryptoJS` seems to be the right way to go. Could you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: Hi I've attached my code. However this throws me a TypeError. I'm not sure what is the correct way of handling file reading in Ionic 2 and should I use File.readAsBinaryString or File.readAsArrayBuffer?

Comment: managed to figure this out?